# GIT Bash error = bash: winpty: command not found

Tags: python-3.x, git, windows-10, anaconda, git-bash

Used windows search; found `python.exe` at: 
C:\Users\Michael\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.6.4-h6538335_1

Entered into GIT Bash:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$PATH:/c/Users/Michael/Anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.4-h6538335_1:/c/Users/Michael/Anaconda3/pkgs/python-3.6.4-h6538335_1/Scripts"' >> .bashrc
$ source .bashrc
$ python --version
```

Received:

> bash: winpty: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I am on a Linux OS, but I would try adding the python.exe path to the Windows path variable (either for the user or globally).

Check this link: [Adding directory to PATH Environment Variable in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9546324/adding-directory-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows)